# AMP form redirection is not working on server

Tags: c#, amp-html

when use the `AMP` form, It redirect to another page on local.. But It deploys to the server, It is not working.
I use below `c#` code there.

```
string body = ReplaceEmailTemplatePlaceHolders(contactUsModel);
string altEmail = _configuration["ALTEmail"];
string altEmailNoReply = _configuration["ALTEmailNoReply"];
string emailSubject = _configuration["ContactUsEmailSubject"];

await _communicationApiService.SendEmailAsync(12, altEmail, contactUsModel.Email, body, emailSubject);
await _communicationApiService.SendEmailAsync(12, altEmailNoReply, altEmail, body, emailSubject);

var url = _configuration["ALTThanksForSubscribing"]; // $"{Request.Scheme}:/{Request.PathBase}";
Response.Headers.Add("AMP-Redirect-To", $"{url}");
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "AMP-Redirect-To");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
return Json(new {Content = ""});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AMP, but my first thought is "What value does `url` get / is it correct / is `ALTThanksForSubscribing` defined in the server's config?"

Comment: Second thought - if the code to send an email failed, maybe it doesn't reach the redirect code... What exception handling/logging is in place; and should it redirect regardless of an error in the email piece?